# Baffled by selectOneMany in Yesod

Tags: database, haskell, persistent, yesod

Sweet but simple, how do Persistent joins work? Consider the following model:

```
Person
    number Int
    numberOfEyes Int
    firstName FirstnamesId
    lastName LastnamesId
Lastnames
    lastname String
Firstnames
    firstname String
```

Assuming I only have the number of a Person, how do I retrieve his full name and the number of his eyes?

I tried looking through the [haskellers.org source](https://github.com/snoyberg/haskellers) but couldn't find any examples of joins. I also checked out the [chapter on joins](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/09/new-book-content) in the yesod book but it only made my eyes spin. The level of my Haskell knowledge is very low so be gentle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways with identical result type:

1. the new typed sql, based on the "[esqueleto](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto)" package from Felipe Lessa which is persistent based
2. and the previous rawSql way

   just add 1 or 2 as argument to the test

---

```
{- file prova.hs-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts, ConstraintKinds, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception  
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Database.Persist.Quasi
import Database.Esqueleto as Esql
import Database.Persist.GenericSql (SqlPersist, rawSql)
import Control.Monad.Logger (MonadLogger)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResourceBase)
import System.Environment (getProgName, getArgs)   
import System.Exit (exitSuccess, exitWith, ExitCode(..))
import Text.Printf (printf)

import QQStr(str)  -- heredoc quasiquoter module

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persist|
Person
    number Int
    numberOfEyes Int
    firstName FirstnamesId
    lastName LastnamesId
    UniquePersonNumber number 
    deriving Show

Lastnames
    lastname String
    deriving Show

Firstnames
    firstname String
    deriving Show
|]

-- the esqueleto way

-- with this type annotation it could be run in a yesod handler with ''runDB''
getPersonInfoByNumber :: (PersistQuery SqlPersist m, MonadLogger m, MonadResourceBase m) => Int -> SqlPersist m (Maybe (Int, String, String))
getPersonInfoByNumber pNumber = do
    result <- select $ from $ \(fn `InnerJoin` p `InnerJoin` ln) -> do
            on ((p ^. PersonFirstName) Esql.==. (fn ^. FirstnamesId))
            on ((p ^. PersonLastName) Esql.==. (ln ^. LastnamesId))
            where_ ((p ^. PersonNumber) Esql.==. val pNumber)
            return (p , fn, ln)

    case result of
        [(Entity _ p, Entity _ fn, Entity _ ln)] -> return $ Just (personNumberOfEyes p, firstnamesFirstname fn, lastnamesLastname ln)
        _ -> return Nothing

-- the rawSql way

stmt = [str|SELECT ??, ??, ??
                          FROM Person, Lastnames, Firstnames
                          ON Person.firstName = Firstnames.id
                          AND Person.lastName = Lastnames.id
                          WHERE Person.number = ?
                         |]
                         
getPersonInfoByNumberRaw :: (PersistQuery SqlPersist m, MonadLogger m, MonadResourceBase m) => Int -> SqlPersist m (Maybe (Int, String, String))
getPersonInfoByNumberRaw pNumber = do
    result <- rawSql stmt [toPersistValue pNumber]

    case result of
        [(Entity _ p, Entity _ fn, Entity _ ln)] -> return $ Just (personNumberOfEyes p, firstnamesFirstname fn, lastnamesLastname ln)
        _ -> return Nothing

        
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    nomProg <- getProgName
    case args of
        [] -> do
             printf "%s: just specify 1 for esqueleto or 2 for rawSql.\n" nomProg
             exitWith (ExitFailure 1)

        [arg] -> (withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ runSqlConn $ do
              runMigration migrateAll
 
              let myNumber = 5
              fnId <- insert $ Firstnames "John"
              lnId <- insert $ Lastnames "Doe"

              -- in case of insert collision, because of UniquePersonNumber constraint
              --    insertUnique does not throw exceptions, returns success in a Maybe result
              --    insert would throw an exception 

              maybePersId <- insertUnique $ Person {personNumber = myNumber, personNumberOfEyes=2,
                                                personFirstName = fnId, personLastName = lnId}

              info <- case arg of
                          "1" -> getPersonInfoByNumber myNumber
                          _ -> getPersonInfoByNumberRaw myNumber
              liftIO $ putStrLn $ show info
              )
              `catch` (\(excep::SomeException) -> 
                               putStrLn $ "AppSqlError: " ++ show excep)
```

extra module for heredoc quasiquoter

```
module QQStr(str) where

import Prelude
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote

str = QuasiQuoter { quoteExp = stringE, quotePat = undefined
                  , quoteType = undefined, quoteDec = undefined }
```

execution:

```
gabi64@zotac-ion:~/webs/yesod/prova$ ./cabal-dev/bin/prova 1
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "Person"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"number" INTEGER NOT NULL,"numberOfEyes" INTEGER NOT NULL,"firstName" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Firstnames","lastName" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Lastnames")
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "Lastnames"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"lastname" VARCHAR NOT NULL)
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "Firstnames"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"firstname" VARCHAR NOT NULL)
Just (2,"John","Doe")
```

Comment: I've since moved on from Haskell but I'll go on a limb and assume this is correct without testing. :)